# Change contents of FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to change the contents of a `FilteringSelect` widget.
I seem to keep running in to this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
```

I've tried changing the `store` to use a `MemoryStore`, I've tried cloning the data and using `setData(data)`.

I've tried just calling `store.put(newItem)` with my new item. This seems to work the first time I do things, but on consecutive changes, I normally end up with `toString`-error.

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="wellsSelectCombo" onChange="selectWell(this.value);" searchAttr="label">
    <option value="Select well(s) on map..."></option>
```

```
var item = {
        label: label,
        id: "feature_content_pane_" + i,            
        index: i
    }; var wellsSelectCombo = dijit.byId('wellsSelectCombo');
wellsSelectCombo.store.put(item);
```

Comment: Maybe the item you are adding is not in the same format of all other items?

Comment: why "value" attribute is missing in item?